# fix_yahoo_finance module (fix-yahoo-finance 0.0.18) - get data for all available dates

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api, stockquotes

I am actively using the fixed yahoo finance module by Ran Aroussi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fix-yahoo-finance) to gather (daily) stock quotes. This is done by the following piece of code:

```
data = yf.download(ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date)
```

My question is though, is there an efficient way to get all the available data without providing a start date and end date?

So as an example, suppose MSFT would have data over a period span of 1990 - now, I'd like to get all this data, without having to provide a start date in 1990.

Comment: But if you don't provide a start date... how does it know when to start? You mean you just want everything?

Comment: Hi Jack, yes, I'd like to get everything - preferably without a significant time delay. I was wondering if there might be something in the module that could allow that, as I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fix-yahoo-finance), describing parameters required:

```
# start date (YYYY-MM-DD / datetime.datetime object)
# (optional, defaults is 1950-01-01)
start = "2017-01-01",
```

So I'm guessing you could simply leave out the `start` param and it would default to 1950, which I would assume is the earliest date on record.

Comment: Hi Jack, unfortunately I get this error, where eeend = datetime.datetime.today(): `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Prices\#yahoo api.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = yf.download(itick, end=eeend)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\fix_yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 141, in download
    start = int(time.mktime(time.strptime('1950-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')))
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range`

Comment: I don't see what this error" is, but if you know what the start date is ("1950-01-01") you could just pass that as the `start` date and you will get all the data available.

Comment: I've tried setting `start` to '2000-01-01', this works fine, however if I set it to '1950-01-01'  I get this error: `File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\fix_yahoo_finance\__init__.py", line 145, in download
    start = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(str(start), '%Y-%m-%d')))
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range`

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be a problem with the actual package itself then - the default date (whether left blank or inserted manually) is out of range. I think your only option would be to contact the developers or report it as a bug.